# how to use okta refresh token in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, okta, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

Can someone guide on how to use okta refresh token in a react app? Checked the documentation but didnt help much,

```
for eg, what is the state in below request?

**GET https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?client_id=${clientId}
 &response_type=code
 &scope=openid%20offline_access
 &redirect_uri=ourApp%3A%2Fcallback
 &state=237c671a-29d7-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002**


this is my okta config   oidc: {
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    issuer: ISSUER,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
    pkce: true,
    disableHttpsCheck: OKTA_TESTING_DISABLEHTTPSCHECK,
    postLogoutRedirectUri:REDIRECT_URI,
    responseType: ['id_token', 'token','refresh_token'],
  },
  resourceServer: {
    messagesUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/api/messages',
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use okta with react you should check [here.](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa/react/before-you-begin/)

To get tokens in your app, the authorization server will redirect back to the react app with the token in a parameter.

I'm guessing okta has a client library for that if they are charging for it.

Comment: I am getting the access token and Id token, but not refresh token. please advise on that

Answer (score 1):

You need to request `offline` scope to get a refresh token, assuming your app/authZ server allow that in their policy

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#tokenmanagerrenewkey
You don't even need a refresh token, necessarily, if you have an active session.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).